# Trait not registred: attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, factory-bot

Having trouble getting this done.
I am using seed.rb + factory_girl to populate database with rake db:seed.

(I know that fixtures exists, but I want to get this done this way, this is just an example, the DB will be populated with complex association objects.)

My seed.rb:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
["QM","CDC","SI","QS"].each do |n|
  FactoryGirl.create(:grau, nome: n)
end
```

and my /factories/graus.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :grau do
    nome
  end
end
```

but when I run:

> rake db:seed

I get:

```
rake aborted!
Trait not registered: nome

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add some default value for nome:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :grau do
    nome 'lorem'
  end
end
```